# Symfony2/Javascript delete alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

the main part of this question relates to how I can define a route in a javascript file.  At the same time, I just want to make sure what I am doing is ok.  Essentially, on my view page, I can see my records.  When I output the records, each row I give

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delete_alert( {{ alert[0].id }} )"/>
```

This gives the user the option to delete an alert.  Before going straight into things, I like to first send it to javascript.

```
function delete_alert(id){
    var answer = confirm("Confirm delete");
    if (answer){
        $.get("NickAlertBundle_delete", { row: id });
    }
}
```

So if the delete is confirmed, it calls this route

```
NickAlertBundle_delete:
    pattern:  /view-alerts
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:delete }
    requirements:
       _method:  GET
```

My first question here is they are deleting the alert from the view-alerts page.  Once they confirm deletion, I dont want them to go anywhere, just have the view-alerts page refresh (as this will remove the deleted alert).  But is giving the delete route a pattern of view-alerts confusing or wrong to do?  Its what I want to do as I want them to stay on this page, just doesnt feel right.

Anyway, my real problem is the error

> No route found for GET /NickAlertBundle_delete (from
>   http://localhost:8000/view-alerts;) (404 Not Found)

So I dont think the way I have define the route in my javascript file is correct.  So how can I fix this route?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use an URL as a first parameter to jQuery `get`. You are currently using the Symfony2 route name, not the URL.

Change it to `/alert-views`.

**OR:**

You can add a data attribute to your HTML button that would contain your path, If you are using Twig as templating engine, you can write something like:

```
data-url={{path('NickAlertBundle_delete')}}
```

Then using the `attr()` jQuery function onclick on your button:

```
var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
```

Finally, the jQuery `get` function can be sent to `url`.

I hope it helps.